What buttons should I put where? (Start, Credits, options, Quit)
which options should go in which boxes (Start, Credits, options, Quit) 

Whichever you need in whatever order you like them. From a single "Play" to twenty-plus different ones leading top all the things. In a typical western market people will prefer Left-To-Right order, but this is not a must.

Have you looked at the menus of other games in a similar niche to yours to see what conventions they use? You're not required to follow the pack, but it can make things more intuitive for players who are already familiar with other games.

And ultimatively there is no right answer. Sure, having quit as the first button and default selected might be a bit user unfriendly. But maybe your game aims to inflict as much pain on the user as it can (though in that case the Start button should be after the credits flow).

Regarding the opinion based nature of the question: while it is subjective & maybe a little narrow in scope, addressing the general problem of UI layout is useful, especially to newer devs. A couple of the comment-answers could be expanded into full answers. Provided we don't have a prior duplicate question, I think this is on-topic as "good subjective."

your question is very much like what color should I paint my fence?

you are using inconsistent programming practice ... options starts with a lower case letter, the other three do not

@jsotola Programming practice does not apply to written English. The list of buttons is not code, and there's no reason to assume that madfroggy would use the same capitalization in the code as in the question.

@Kevin are you saying that button label consistency is not a programming practice? ... maybe I'm misunderstanding what you are saying

@jsotola The words "Start, Credits, options, Quit" in the question are not code. It's just a list of words in English. Yes, it looks weird that one of them isn't capitalized, but that's not "bad programming practice", any more than the lack of capitalization in your comments is "bad programming practice". There's no reason to assume that the button labels will be identical to how this question is written; for all we know, the final labels could be "PLAY", "SETTINGS", "CREDITS", "EXIT".

@Kevin now I understand what you are telling me ... thank you

While this question seems subjective at first, I think we can pretty easily apply some standard menu rules and come up with an objective answer.

"Start" should always be first (it's the most important button and the one that players will be looking for most often).
"Quit" should always be last (this makes it easy to find).
"Options" is more important than "Credits" (most players will never click on "Credits"), so it should come before "Credits".

Using these rules, the order from first to last should be Start, Options, Credits, Quit.
